# Arduino C++, unable to convert String to char*

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to make a bluetooth macro keyboard, with key assignments .
Almost all is working except the macro sequence conversion from String to char*.

This is necessary because if the String is passed to the bleKeyboard.print() command, it will print "\r\n" literally instead of new line.

So what I want to do is:

1. Read line from text file on SD and put it into "parameter" - this works, and is String
2. Convert the content of the "parameter" into "chararray"
3. Assign the "chararray" to next item of macro_keys[15] array
   and loop steps 1-3 for all keys.

This simplified code should work, but chararray is blank:

```
String parameter;
char* macro_keys[15];
char* chararray;

Serial.begin(115200);

parameter="default1";
//int str_len = sizeof(parameter);
int str_len = parameter.length(); // Thank you David Schwartz
str_len++;
parameter.toCharArray(chararray,str_len);
Serial.print("parameter: ");Serial.println(parameter);
Serial.print("str_len: ");Serial.println(str_len);
Serial.print("chararray: ");Serial.println(chararray);
```

You can check this sketch or suggested changes - preloaded on [ESP32 code simulator on wokwi.com](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/320167722594861650)

What is wrong here?

To add some clarification, more information of what I am trying to build:

https://github.com/ekoslav/ESP32_Password_keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
int str_len = sizeof(parameter);
```

The `sizeof` a string is not the length of the contents of the string. The size of a variable does *not* depend on the value or contents of the variable while the length of a string (obviously) does depend on the value.

Perhaps you mean `paramater.size()`?

Second:

```
parameter.toCharArray(chararray,str_len);
```

You forgot to assign a value to `chararray`. So you are passing a garbage value to `toCharArray`. The docs say that the first parameter to `toCharArray` must be the buffer to copy characters into. Nowhere in your code do you create any such buffer.

Third:

```
char* theArray[15];
```

Maybe this was supposed to create a buffer, but it doesn't. It creates an array of 15 *pointers*. What do you need 15 pointers for?

Comment: sketch.ino:9:25: error: 'class String' has no member named 'size'
 int str_len = parameter.size();

Comment: It might be `length` on your platform. See [here](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/strings/StringLength).

Comment: chararray is a buffer, where the content of string parameter should be stored as a char* array

Comment: But `chararray` is not a buffer. It's a pointer, and it doesn't point to any buffer. If it's a buffer, how big a buffer is it?

Comment: the use of this is to assign values for each key of 4x4 keyboard

Comment: int str_len = parameter.length();   This does work properly, however does not help with the conversion issue. Thank you for this :)

Comment: charraray shoud be str_len size, or maybe str_len + 1

Comment: @Eki Except it isn't, it's just a pointer that doesn't point to anything. You need a buffer of size `str_len + 1`. But nowhere do you allocate one. Instead, you pass an uninitialized value to `toCharArray`. Where in your code do you think you actually allocate a buffer of that size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240845/discussion-between-eki-and-david-schwartz).